# The number of conditions on the keys is invalid when using partition key only in DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-dynamodb, primary-key

I understand the existence of two keys in dynamoDB from [here](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/). I choose the use the partition key only but I still get the error:

```
The number of conditions on the keys is invalid
```

Here is my table schema file:

```
Created table. Table description JSON: {
  "TableDescription": {
    "AttributeDefinitions": [
      {
        "AttributeName": "id",
        "AttributeType": "S"
      }
    ],
    "TableName": "MyMovies",
    "KeySchema": [
      {
        "AttributeName": "id",
        "KeyType": "HASH"
      }
    ],
    "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
    "CreationDateTime": "2021-03-06T16:44:22.790Z",
    "ProvisionedThroughput": {
      "LastIncreaseDateTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "LastDecreaseDateTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
      "ReadCapacityUnits": 10,
      "WriteCapacityUnits": 10
    },
    "TableSizeBytes": 0,
    "ItemCount": 0,
    "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/MyMovies"
  }
}
```

When I try to delete item in the db, and the error occurred:

```
async delete(id: string): Promise<Movie> {
        let movie;
        try {
            const result = await dynamoDB
            .get({
                TableName: "MyMovies",
                Key:{
                    "id": id,
                }
            })
            .promise();
            movie = result.Item;
        } catch (error) {
            throw new InternalServerErrorException(error);
        }

        try {
            await dynamoDB
              .delete({
                TableName: "MyMovies",
                Key: { 
                    "id": id,
                },
              })
              .promise();
          } catch (error) {
            throw new InternalServerErrorException(error);
          }
        return movie;
    }
```

How can I use the partition key only and get or delete item from the dynamoDB successfully?

Comment: for the given table definition,  code you have written looks perfect and should work. Only way that will result in given error is when you have a Range/Sort key also in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the issue is not from dynamoDB, and it causes from the id is always `undefined` in my code. Because I didn't pass the correct id from my resolver.

Before:

```
@Mutation(() => Movie, {description: "Delete a movie from the DynamoDB."})
    async deleteMovie(@Args('input') id: string,) {
        return await this.movieService.delete(id)
    }
```

After:

```
@Mutation(() => Movie, {description: "Delete a movie from the DynamoDB."})
    async deleteMovie(@Args('id') id: string,) {
        return await this.movieService.delete(id)
    }
```

The above code is working after I change `id` from `input`.